# Identification of Youtube Player Code

Tags: video, youtube-api, embed, playlist, shockwave

I need to amend the following code to fit another Youtube playlist or group of vids. All of the API options note youtube.com/v/ or simply use iframe. What is this code in accord with Youtube, and how can I amend the info to display my choice video grouping?

`<object width="746" height="413" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/cp/vjVQa1PpcFNjzNDvQMfltuY8R7M_XEXZ7YRz2wgBe1I=" /><embed width="746" height="413" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/cp/vjVQa1PpcFNjzNDvQMfltuY8R7M_XEXZ7YRz2wgBe1I=" /></object>`

Thanks

Comment: you need to actually add your code if you want to get help for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the YouTube Custom Player. That's been deprecated for a couple of years now: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/06/sunsetting-custom-player.html

There are some other options mentioned in that blog post for sharing playlists.